# Changing data in an Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, variables, object, methods

I have been trying to make a game for a friend, but I'm having a problem with getting my line `player[i].setName(getName(pn));` in class `Players` to work. I want to be able to set the names of the players, or change them, in the list. but I keep getting errors at this line. This happened after i changed the `public` variables in class `Player` from `static`.

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at worldhomicide.drinkinggame.PlayerInfo.Players.setPlayers(Players.java:16)
>       at worldhomicide.drinkinggame.main.Game.main(Game.java:25)"

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I posted all needed code below.

**Game Class**

```
public class Game{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MessageHandler.gameRules(); // Display Game Information
        Players.getAmount();Players.setPlayers();   // Get player data

        System.out.println("What player would you like to look up?");
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(EventHandler.keyboard.next()); choice -= 1;
        System.out.println(Players.player[choice].name);


    }

}
```

**Players Class**

```
public class Players extends EventHandler {

    public static int playerAmount;
    public static Player[] player;

    public static void setPlayers(){    
        player = new Player[playerAmount];

        for(int i = 0; i < player.length; i++){
            int pn = i+1;
            player[i].setName(getName(pn));
        }
    }

    public static void getAmount(){
        MessageHandler.playerAmount();
        playerAmount = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.next());
    }


}
```

**Class EventHandler**

```
public class EventHandler {

    public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String getName(int playerNumber){
        System.out.println("What is player " + playerNumber + "'s name?");
        String name = keyboard.next();      
        return name;

    }

}
```

**Player Class**

```
public class Player {

    public String name;
    public int score;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: _"...i keep getting errors..."_ -- If you don't share the errors with us how can you expect to get any help?  [edit] your post and include the complete error message and stack trace if applicable.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at worldhomicide.drinkinggame.PlayerInfo.Players.setPlayers(Players.java:16)
 at worldhomicide.drinkinggame.main.Game.main(Game.java:25)

Comment: Don't post crucial information in comments. [edit] it into your original question.

Comment: Anything to help me edit the variable name in the object player.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that in your `setPlayers()` method, inside the loop, you didn't create Player object before accessing the `player[i].setName()` method.

```
for(int i = 0; i < player.length; i++){
    int pn = i+1;
    player[i] = new Player(); //you need to create Player object
    player[i].setName(getName(pn));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was giving me the biggest headache. Works the way it should now!

Comment: Moreover in your Game class main method you are not creating any object for Players.

Comment: He is using  static methods of Players class. So in this case no need to create Players object. Correct me if I am wrong. @Abhishekkumar

Comment: @Nourin.Eka - you are right. I missed the static part.